# SpriteRenderers not getting batched

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, render

I have a game with like 100 draw calls. But all i have on scene is my background(which is made from 100 gameobjects with spriterenderer and collider). I don't get why those are not batched. I use the same settings for them all. All I change is sprite, othervise totaly the same objects.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you say 'all I change is the sprite', do you mean you're changing textures? That would prevent batching right there...

Comment: I finaly found a solution. The problem was that sprites werent in sprite atlas. So whn i added them i got to 20 draw calls!

Answer (score -3):

buddy you should put all your sprites inside atlas (sprite sheet), other wise you will have a draw call for each texture that you have in your scene

Comment: This question was answered in 2013 as proof by the OPs last comment.